# how to retrive a collection of instance through loop in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

i wonder to know how to get the attribute of an object in a collection of instances
note: this collection is in the hasmany relation and here is the code

```
protected $fillable = ['title','description','client_id','product_id'];
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Client','id','client_id');
}
public function products(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product','id','product_id');
}
```

controller

```
 $clients = Invoice::with('user','products')->get();
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice),compact('clients',$clients));
```

view

```
 @foreach($clients as $client)
 <td>{{ $client->user->title ?? 'no users' }}</td>
<td>{{ $client->products->name ?? 'no products '  }}</td>
   @endforeach
```

and here is the dd of my $client

```
#observables: []
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "user" => Client {#310 ▶}
    "products" => Collection {#316 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Product {#312 ▼
          #fillable: array:5 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:8 [▶]
          #original: array:8 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
```

here the is no problem with the user relation because its 1 to 1 and can be retrieved but i cant get the product items in view

Comment: Please Post product model code.

Comment: class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','price','cat_id','stock'];
    public  function product_cat() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCat','id' , 'cat_id');
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Because you are having One to One relationship, you should use **first()** instead of **get()** Try to change your query like this

```
$clients = Invoice::with('user','products')->first();
return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice', $invoice),compact('clients',$clients));
```

and in your view you can access your product with

```
{{ $clients->products->name }}
{{ $clients->products->description }}
```

**Update**

Change your model code to

```
public function products(){ return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id','product_id'); }
```

And in your view

```
@foreach($clients->products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yeah thats right. It should work. Otherwise I posted another answer. But this one is better

Comment: thanks but i get the error again Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Answer (score 0):

Products is an array of object. But take a look at ***Amandeep Singh*** answer

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
<td>{{ $client->user->title ?? 'no users' }}</td>
<td>{{ $client->products[0]->name ?? 'no products '  }}</td>
@endforeach
```